# Deploy archive with JFrog CLI without overwriting existing packages

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I'm trying to set up an automated process for uploading archives of artifacts to a repo, without overwriting any existing packages. (to keep custom properties, original uploader metadata, etc.)

When I do this through the UI using an "underpriveleged" user (Only has Read, Annotate, and Deploy/Cache permissions, as confirmed by looking at that user in the `Effective Permissions` tab for the relevant repo), by clicking `Deploy` then selecting `Deploy as Bundle Artifact` it works fine, and appears to only upload the packages that don't exist.

But when I try to do the same, with the same user, through the JFrog CLI I keep on getting errors.

JFrog CLI:

```
jfrog rt u --explode=true --props="..." <path to zip> <repo name>
```

JFrog CLI Response:

```
[Error] [Thread 2] Artifactory response: 403 Forbidden
```

When attempting the same with a user that has Delete/Overwrite permissions the requests work fine, but they overwrite any existing packages and all those package's metadata.

Is there a way to upload only the artifacts that don't exist using the CLI like this?